# Tracking employee data

Tags: performance, php, mysql, mysqli

We have **hundreds** of employees and for tracking each employees' data, and I am using this code:

```
<?php
$sqldelivery9 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM orders WHERE employeename = 'nawaz' AND DATE(reattemptdate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)";
$resultdeliverys9 = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqldelivery9); 
$numrowsresultdelivery9 =$resultdeliverys9[0]['count'];         
echo $numrowsresultdelivery9;
```

Also, I am tracking the **last 7 days** of records of each employee, so it's going to be **100*7= 700 SQL queries**. Is this acceptable? Will it going to affect performance? Is there any better way to do it with **minimal SQL queries**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. You can do that all in a single query.

```
SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM orders
    WHERE employeename in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', '...')
        AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    GROUP BY employeename, date
```

This will give you data in the form of

```
name1 | 2018-09-05 | 5
name1 | 2018-09-06 | 7
name1 | 2018-09-07 | 12
name1 | 2018-09-08 | 9
name1 | 2018-09-09 | 22
name2 | 2018-09-05 | 3
name2 | 2018-09-06 | 5
name2 | 2018-09-07 | 9
name2 | 2018-09-08 | 11
name2 | 2018-09-09 | 16
...
```

All you need is to iterate over the data.

Of course you can drop the `employeename in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', '...')` condition if you want to search over **ALL** employees and not just "specific n" ones.

Comment: Thanks , i tried your code : `$sqldelivery9 = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM orders
    WHERE employeename in ('nawaz', 'asha')
        AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    GROUP BY employeename, date";
$resultdeliverys9 = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqldelivery9); 
$numrowsresultdelivery9 =$resultdeliverys9[0]['count'];         
echo $numrowsresultdelivery9;` , i got result as `9` , but did't got result as you posted in answer..... please tell me what wrong i done ?

Comment: also when i used `$sqldelivery9 = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM orders AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    GROUP BY employeename, date";
$resultdeliverys9 = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqldelivery9); 
$numrowsresultdelivery9 =$resultdeliverys9[0]['count'];         
echo $numrowsresultdelivery9;` i got error : `Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual  corresponds to your MySQL server version for syntax to use near 'AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY employeenam'`

Comment: The above is the total data returned. You have to iterate over each result. You are just accessing the **first** result. You have to do it in a loop

Comment: sorry, i did't know that, is i need to use foreach loop ?

Comment: Yea. Your first query only returns one row. My queries returns multiple rows, one row for each day for each employee (100 employees a 7 days should give you 700 rows)

Comment: now i tried like this code, please check : https://pastebin.com/2bHBNDb7 ,  i got result  as : 999999999999

Comment: @vickeycolors: thats because you echoing `$numrowsresultdelivery9` instead of `$resultdelivery9` (singular one) and you don't add any spaces in between the results.... that should actually be a separate question and you should first start with some programming basics, seems like you did not a lot of programming so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82951/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-tseng).

Comment: I am really sorry for that,  i am learning programming,  i tried `echo $resultdelivery9['count']."<br>";` , i got result as `9
16
10
5
28
3
1
23
46
21
34
25`

Comment: now i am trying to get the employee name & date , is this correct way ? :- `foreach ($resultdeliverys9 as $resultdelivery9) 
{
 
 echo " " . date("Y-m-d")." ";
 echo "nawaz"." ";
 echo $resultdelivery9['count']."<br>";
}`

Comment: In DB, when i run query in phpmyadmin, i got perfect result : http://prntscr.com/ksnomn , but in php page, its display as `9

58` without displaying employee name & date, please help me for this....  code : `$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) 
as count FROM orders WHERE employeename in ('nawaz' , 'asha') 
AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
 GROUP BY employeename, date"; 
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];       

foreach ($results as $result) 
{
 
 echo $result['count']."<br>";
}`

Comment: @vickeycolors: You should ask that other question on https://stackoverflow.com (which is also part of StackExchange) as it's a different issue, this would go far to off-topic on this question and StackExchange site

Comment: sorry , i will ask there......

Answer (score 2):

The query you need is like

```
SELECT emploee_name, DATE(reattemptdate), count(*) cnt 
FROM orders WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY emploee_name, DATE(reattemptdate)
```

However, its performance could be *worse* than that of 700 separate queries. Index have to be created carefully, with emploee_name, DATE(reattemptdate) al the last elements of it. For the purpose you may need to create a separate column consists of the result DATE(reattemptdate).

To get the result conveniently in PHP, you can use vanilla PDO which is significantly better than any stuff that you are using at the moment.

```
$sql = "SELECT emploee_name, DATE(reattemptdate), count(*) cnt 
FROM orders WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY emploee_name, DATE(reattemptdate)";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

will give you a convenient array where data will be [grouped by the employee name](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP) which you can simply iterate over using a nested `foreach`.

Comment: If the index are missing he'd have the same performance issue on every single query multiplied with 700. The aggregated query uses the same two fields

Comment: @Tseng inexes do not work that straightforward. Different queries use different indexes.